# How to get the Month and Year to show up together in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having some trouble with trying to get the year to show up alongside the month name in SSRS 2012.
I have tried changing the number to date and select different options but none seem to be working.  I have also tried changing the number to date in the Text Box Properties and in the Placeholder Properties but no luck. Any ideas? 
[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqE3g.png)

Comment: How are you displaying the name of the month?

Comment: It is just on the default at the moment.  Trying to get it so users can see the year that month is with.

Comment: I was looking at where I pulled MonthName from and in SSMS it was set to nvarchar(255) instead of datetime.  Would that be why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that the field is in a date format, select text box properties, select number,select date category, select "January 2000" from the Type list box.

Comment: I was looking at where I pulled MonthName from and in SSMS it was set to nvarchar(255) instead of datetime.  Would that be why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Select text box, go to the properties window (F4) and type **MMMM yyyy** into the Format section

[image: format properties]